# How do I replace(sub) the word in this situation

Tags: python, regex

Im working on Tensorflow project and building Object detection API wrapper.
What I want to do is replacing this particular part of file `"PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/mscoco_train.record"`with some value while preserving everything else as it is. How do you do that using `re`module? 
There are couple block that is similar to this, so I need to specify the scope from `train_input_reader`. 
I tried various things but none of them worked correctly so Im asking.

```
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: test
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/mscoco_train.record"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Comment: Can you edit your question with the desired result, at the moment it's unclear if you want to replace `'PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED'`, the file itself or the entire path

Comment: @Rakesh It isn't dictionary. What I wanna do is replacing that particular part while preserving as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`

```
re.sub(r'input_path:\s+"[^"]*"', 'input_path: "{}"'.format(new_path), s)
```

For example,

```
>>> import re
>>> new_path = "new_path"
>>> s="""train_input_reader {
...   label_map_path: test
...   tf_record_input_reader {
...     input_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/mscoco_train.record"
...   }
... }"""
>>> s = re.sub(r'input_path:\s+"[^"]*"', 'input_path: "{}"'.format(new_path), s)
>>>
>>> print(s)
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: test
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "new"
  }
}
>>>
```